# Deactivate plugin on registration

Tags: plugin-development, comparison, activation

I'd like to check if the server is running PHP5.2. To do this, I use a activation-hook which will be registered with "register_activation_hook". Instead of just returning a warning, i'd like to auto-disable the plugin and redirect to the plugins.php in WP-Dashboard.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. No error or other output. The activation-hook fires correclty, tested with a wp_die().

What I'm doing wrong here?

```
    register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'MyActivationHook');
    function MyActivationHook() {
        if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '111.2', '<')) {
            deactivate_plugins(plugin_basename(__FILE__));
            wp_redirect(admin_url('plugins.php')); 
            //wp_die(printf(__('Sorry, you need at least PHP version %1s to use this plugin. Your current PHP version is %2s.', 'textdomain'), '5.2', PHP_VERSION));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have to `exit;` after a redirect.